# return or continue or what else? in a menu python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have this code to convert the temperature to celsius,kelvin or fahrenheit:

**The code is fine, I mean performs the function of the operation**

**but I need to return/back to the operation, ¿how can I do that?**

```
Centrigrados = 1
Fahrenheit = 2
Kelvin = 3

numero = int(input("Introduce un numero: "))
origen = int(input("Agrega la escala de origen: "))
destino = int(input("Agrega la escala de destino: "))

if numero > 0 and origen == 1:
    print("Has elegido grados Centigrados")
    if destino == 2:
        print("La conversion será en grados Fahrenheit")
        print("El resultado es: ", (int(numero * 1.8+32)))
    if destino == 3:
        print("La conversion será en grados Kelvin")
        print("Y el resultado es: ", numero + 273.15)

if numero > 0 and origen == 2:
    print("Has elegido grados Fahrenheit")
    if destino == 1:
        print("La conversión será en grados Centigrados")
        print("Y el resultado es: ", (numero - 32) * 5//9)
    if destino == 3:
        print("La conversión será en grados Kelvin")
        print("Y el resultado es: ", (numero + 459.67) * 5/9)

if numero > 0 and origen == 3:
    print("Has elegido grados Kelvin")
    if destino == 1:
        print("La conversión será en grados Centigrados")
        print("Y el resultado es: ", numero - 273.15)
    if destino == 2:
        print("La conversion será en grados Fahrenheit")
        x = (numero - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32 #realizando operacion kelvin-fahrenheit
        print("Y el resultado es: ", "{:.2f}".format(x)) #formateando el resultado a los 2 ultimos decimales
```

Comment: at the top write `def convert():` and indent the rest of your script ... then at the bottom add `while 1: convert()`

Comment: Wrap everything (except constant definitions at the beginning) in a "while True:" loop which you can "break" to terminate the program.

Comment: @JoranBeasley `while 1:` should be `while True:`. They both work, but `True` is more idiomatic for booleans.